# Redirection in laravel without return statement

Tags: php, laravel

i have this blogsController, the create function is as follows.

```
public function create() {
  if($this->reqLogin()) return $this->reqLogin();
  return View::make('blogs.create');
 }
```

In BaseController, i have this function which checks if user is logged in.

```
    public function reqLogin(){
      if(!Auth::check()){
        Session::flash('message', 'You need to login');
        return Redirect::to("login");
      }
    }
```

This code is working fine , but it is not what is need i want my create function as follows.

```
public function create() {
  $this->reqLogin();
  return View::make('blogs.create');
 }
```

Can i do so?

Apart from that, can i set authantication rules , like we do in **Yii** framework, at the top of controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put the check into a filter, then only let the user get to the controller if they are logged in in the first place.

Filter

```
Route::filter('auth', function($route, $request, $response)
{
    if(!Auth::check()) {
       Session::flash('message', 'You need to login');
       return Redirect::to("login");
    }
});
```

Route

```
Route::get('blogs/create', array('before' => 'auth', 'uses' => 'BlogsController@create'));
```

Controller

```
public function create() {
  return View::make('blogs.create');
 }
```

Comment: This works!, so do i need to add route for every action i need authorization for?

Comment: Look at Route::group() in the Laravel docs. Basically make one "group" of authorisated routes together.

Answer (score 19):

Beside organizing your code to fit better Laravel's architecture, there's a little trick you can use when returning a response is not possible and a redirect is absolutely needed.

The trick is to call `\App::abort()` and pass the approriate code and headers. This will work in most of the circumstances (excluding, notably, blade views and `__toString()` methods.

**Here's a simple function that will work everywhere**, no matter what, *while still keeping your shutdown logic intact*.

```
/**
 * Redirect the user no matter what. No need to use a return
 * statement. Also avoids the trap put in place by the Blade Compiler.
 *
 * @param string $url
 * @param int $code http code for the redirect (should be 302 or 301)
 */
function redirect_now($url, $code = 302)
{
    try {
        \App::abort($code, '', ['Location' => $url]);
    } catch (\Exception $exception) {
        // the blade compiler catches exceptions and rethrows them
        // as ErrorExceptions :(
        //
        // also the __toString() magic method cannot throw exceptions
        // in that case also we need to manually call the exception
        // handler
        $previousErrorHandler = set_exception_handler(function () {
        });
        restore_error_handler();
        call_user_func($previousErrorHandler, $exception);
        die;
    }
}
```

Usage in PHP:

```
redirect_now('/');
```

Usage in Blade:

```
{{ redirect_now('/') }}
```

Answer (score 3):

We can do like this,

```
throw new \Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\HttpResponseException(redirect('/to/another/route/')->with('status', 'An error occurred.'));
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not a best practice to use this method, but to solve your question, you can use this [gist](https://gist.github.com/molayli/2cde1317bb81fd2734fdd1a6f63ce46c).

Create a helper function like:

```php
if(!function_exists('abortTo')) {
  function abortTo($to = '/') {
    throw new \Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\HttpResponseException(redirect($to));
  }
}
```

then use it in your code:

```php
public function reqLogin(){
  if(!Auth::check()){
    abortTo(route('login'));
  }
}
```

```php
public function create() {
  $this->reqLogin();
  return View::make('blogs.create');
}
```

Comment: You have to change "Exception" into "Exceptions".